# php sybase config problem:undefined function sybase_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, xampp, sybase

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcgear\index.php on line 3

```
  <?php
$link = sybase_connect('MIKE', 'sa', '')
        or die("Could not connect !");
echo "Connected successfully";
sybase_close($link);
?>
```

Sybase and Apache themselves work. but php can't connect to sybase

I have uncommented out extension=php_sybase_ct.dll and turn on magic_quotes_sybase = On @ c:\xampp\php\php.ini

I use Windows 7 Ultimate, xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6-installer,sybase ase155esd2_winx86.

Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Was anybody successfully able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possibilities:

1. First try to restart Apache and give it another try;
2. See if php.ini file is well configured;
3. And make sure the sybase ext has no ";" or " " information on it.

> ```
> php.ini:
> (...)
> ;extension=php_sqlite.dll
> extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
> ;extension=php_tidy.dll
> (...)</li>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since `sybase_connect` didn't work for me, I went for `odbc_connect('database', 'login', 'pw')` and it worked for me.

```
- Windows 10 64 bits Profesional
- XAMPP 3.2.2 (12th Nov 2015)
- Sybase SQL Anywhere 8
- Inside php.ini -> "extension=php_sybase_ct.dll" without ";".
- ODBC (32bits) configured with Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0 controler and the ODBC login has password, maybe is required*.
```

To configure ODBC go to: *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Orígenes de datos ODBC (32 bits)*
or *C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\odbcad32.exe*

Sometimes in the Network section when configuring the ODBC you have to enable "TCP/IP" and for example write "Host=127.0.0.1" <- I sometimes forget to put "Host=" and it doesn't work at all. Make sure to press the "Test Connection" in the ODBC tab before trying to connect via PHP.

I found this old post while looking for a solution to a problem with how to connect PHP to sybase. Hope if someone finds this post, "my" solution works as for him too.